# Clipping a line to a polygon extent segments the line into pieces in ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, clip

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1. and I have a polyline layer of the coastline of Mexico, but I would like to clip this line so that I just have the coastline of the North Pacific states. I have the polygon of the merged North Pacific states, but when I try to clip the coastline to the extent of the the state polygon layer (or even intersect), the output splits my coastline into small segments instead of one continuous line.

Troubleshooting I've tried:

- I've tried to do a geometry repair on each layer but that did not work either
- I buffered the coastline so that it changed to a polygon, then tried to clip that layer to the state layer, and the output still came out segmented like in the third image.

-I've tried using coastline layers from different sources

Any other suggestions on how to keep the clipped coastline as one continuous line?

Here are some screenshots:
[image: North Pacific polygon]

[image: Coastline polyline that I would like to clip]

[image: Output of clipped coastline (see like is segmented now and not a continuous line)]

Comment: Your line layer is not a perfect match to your polygon layer, so a clip keeps some and gets rid of some of the line.  Instead I would just split the line layer on the south near Guadalajara in a simple edit session using the split line tool and snapping/tracing to the polygon at that point, then deleting the line parts you don't need.

Comment: Indeed, this seems more like a poor registration issue, not a defective algorithm.